# Regex only searching for words

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex that works fine in http://regexpal.com/:

```
[^-:1234567890/.,\s]*
```

I am trying to find in a paragraph full of ( `, . # "" \n \s`...etc) just the words

but in my code i cannot see the result i am specting:

```
def words(lines):
    words_pattern = re.compile(r'[^-:1234567890/.,\s]*')
    li = []
    for m in lines:
        e = words_pattern.search(m)
        if e:
            match = e.group()
            li.append(match)
    return li

li = [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

Any advice on this? maybe i am not traspassing the regex in the right way from one place to another

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

To be more precise i do want: ñ á é í ó and ú

thanks

Comment: instead of using the "not" group, use \w for letters or [A-Z,a-z] for upper or lower case letters

Comment: Note that `1234567890` can be written `\d`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the letters you could use `string.ascii_letters`

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> import re
>>> s = 'this is 123 some text! that has someñ \n other stuff.'
>>> re.findall('[{}]+'.format(ascii_letters), s)
['this', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'that', 'has', 'some', 'other', 'stuff']
```

You can also get the same behavior from `[A-Za-z]` (which is essentially the same thing as `string.ascii_letters`)

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Za-z]+', s)
['this', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'that', 'has', 'some', 'other', 'stuff']
```

Comment: Is not finding á but i will mark it as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want `'á'` but not `'ñ'`? Are you able to fully enumerate the set of characters you *do* want to keep? That is basically what you have to put in the `[ ]` character set

Comment: just modified the question